# jQuery off() and bind(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

I am trying to remove an event handler from an element, attaching with jQuery's `on()` and removing it with `off()`. This normally will work, but in this case it doesn't do a thing.

```
this.element.on('click', this.handler);
this.element.off('click', this.handler);
```

This will work, but in my case it isn't working because of binding the scope to the handler.

```
this.element.on('click', this.handler.bind(this));
this.element.off('click', this.handler.bind(this));
```

Because of the scope is getting bound to the handler, the `off` method can't detach the event from the element.

I've tried using a reference, like so:

```
var self = this;
this.element.on('click', this.handler.bind(self));
this.element.off('click', this.handler.bind(self));
```

But no luck... anybody have an idea to solve this issue?

Comment: Try storing the result of `this.handler.bind(self)` in a variable and passing it by reference. For the unbind to work, if you pass a function to it, the function must be the same function that was passed to the binding. calling .bind() again creates a new function.

Comment: Smart move! Yes that will work, but makes my code kinda sloppy, in this case I need to rewrite a lot of code, and make it a method/property of my class, because my attaing and detaching is not in the same function.

Comment: Can't you do what Dan did in his answer? or is it more complicated than that.

Comment: You could also instead namespace your events so that you can remove specific events by namespace rather than handler.

Comment: Thanks, yes what Dan has said is the same as what you said, I understand now that calling bind again will create a new function and that is the problem of the situation. In that case I have to write a variable of member of the class for every handler. I do prefer a more clean way to do it, can you be more specific about NS events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative solution to storing a reference to a single function would be to use namespaced events.

```
this.element.on('click.iamspecial', this.handler.bind(this));
this.element.off('click.iamspecial');
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try making the explicitly bound thing a reference:

```
var h = this.handler.bind(this);
this.element.on('click', h);
this.element.off('click', h);
```

Comment: Thanks Dan! I will consider this approach. :)